# How to use git-sync image as a sidecar in kubernetes that git pulls periodically

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, sidecar, git-sync

I am trying to use [git-sync](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync) image as a side car in kubernetes that runs git-pull periodically  and mounts cloned data to shared volume.

Everything is working fine when I configure it for sync one time. I want to run it periodically like every 10 mins. Somehow when I configure it to run periodically pod initializing is failing.

I read documentation but couldn't find proper answer. Would be nice if you help me to figure out what I am missing in my configuration.

Here is my configuration that failing.

**Deployment**

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-helloworld
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
              name: www-data
      initContainers:
        - name: git-sync
          image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync:v3.1.3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: www-data
              mountPath: /data
          env:
            - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
              value: "https://github.com/musaalp/design-patterns.git" ##repo-path-you-want-to-clone
            - name: GIT_SYNC_BRANCH
              value: "master" ##repo-branch
            - name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
              value: /data
            - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
              value: "hello" ##path-where-you-want-to-clone
            - name: GIT_SYNC_PERIOD
              value: "10"
            - name: GIT_SYNC_ONE_TIME
              value: "false"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
      volumes:
        - name: www-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

**Pod**

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx-helloworld
  name: nginx-helloworld
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-helloworld
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the `git-sync` as an `initContainers`, which run only during init (once in lifecycle)

> A Pod can have multiple containers running apps within it, but it can also have one or more init containers, which are run before the app containers are started.
>
> Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:
>
> - Init containers always **run to completion**.
> - Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.
>   [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

So use this as a regular container

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: git-sync
          image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync:v3.1.3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: www-data
              mountPath: /data
          env:
            - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
              value: "https://github.com/musaalp/design-patterns.git" ##repo-path-you-want-to-clone
            - name: GIT_SYNC_BRANCH
              value: "master" ##repo-branch
            - name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
              value: /data
            - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
              value: "hello" ##path-where-you-want-to-clone
            - name: GIT_SYNC_PERIOD
              value: "20"
            - name: GIT_SYNC_ONE_TIME
              value: "false"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
        - name: nginx-helloworld
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
              name: www-data
      volumes:
        - name: www-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working as you said as a regular container. I just have another question. I am trying to override sync period by mentioning GIT_SYNC_PERIOD but its not working. I assume its interpreted as second. So value for GIT_SYNC_PERIOD either 45 or 45s didn't work. I basically want git sync every 10min.

Comment: >    --period <duration>, `$GIT_SYNC_PERIOD`
            How long to wait between sync attempts.  This must be at least
            10ms.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync

Comment: Actually thats the problem. It always use the default value which is 10ms. I want to override it.

Comment: can you please open new question and tag me?

Comment: its here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447467/how-to-override-git-sync-sync-period